# one element from list pair with other elements

Tags: python

get one element from list and print it with all next elements according to condition.

```
l = [0,1,2,3]
count = 0
def ab():   
    for index, elem in enumerate(l):
        global count 
        if (index+1 <= len(l) and count+1 < len(l)):
            print('finding from', str(l[count]) ,'to',l[index])         
            if index == len(l)-1:
                count += 1 
                print('pass',count)
                ab()
ab()
```

output of above function

```
pass 0
finding from 0 to 0
finding from 0 to 1 # expect pass 0 to start from here 
finding from 0 to 2
finding from 0 to 3

pass 1
finding from 1 to 0
finding from 1 to 1
finding from 1 to 2  #  expect to start from here  
finding from 1 to 3
pass 2
finding from 2 to 0
finding from 2 to 1
finding from 2 to 2
finding from 2 to 3  #  expect to start from here
```

what i expect - get element from list and pair with values  after  it  not  before

```
pass 0
finding from 0 to 1 
finding from 0 to 2
finding from 0 to 3
pass 1
finding from 1 to 2         
finding from 1 to 3
pass 2
finding from 2 to 3
```

Comment: Your list doesn't have 3 so how do you expect to print 3?

Comment: The output you posted doesn't match what the code provides

Comment: sorry for that . made changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've made this more complicated than it needs to be. You just need a loop within a loop like this:

```
L = [0,1,2]

for i in range(len(L)):
    print(f'pass {i}')
    for j in range(i, len(L)):
        print(f'finding from {i} to {j+1}')
```